# CVXOPT constraint-related error: Rank(A) < p or Rank([P; A; G]) < n

Tags: python, algorithm, cvxpy, convex-optimization, cvxopt

I want to run the [GRAM](https://mklpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/GRAM) algorithm from [MKLpy](https://mklpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on a list of dataframes `mrna_df`, `methylation_df`, and `protein_df`. MKLpy uses `cvxopt` under the hood.

[GRAM](https://mklpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/GRAM) code from [MKLpy](https://mklpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from . import Solution, Cache, TwoStepMKL
from ..arrange import average, summation
from ..utils.misc import uniform_vector
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
from cvxopt import matrix, spdiag, solvers
import numpy as np
import time,sys 
import torch
from ..metrics import ratio



def opt_radius(K, init_sol=None): 
    n = K.shape[0]
    K = matrix(K.numpy())
    P = 2 * K
    p = -matrix([K[i,i] for i in range(n)])
    G = -spdiag([1.0] * n)
    h = matrix([0.0] * n)
    A = matrix([1.0] * n).T
    b = matrix([1.0])
    solvers.options['show_progress']=False
    sol = solvers.qp(P,p,G,h,A,b,initvals=init_sol)
    radius2 = (-p.T * sol['x'])[0] - (sol['x'].T * K * sol['x'])[0]
    return sol, radius2


def opt_margin(K, YY, init_sol=None):
    '''optimized margin evaluation'''
    n = K.shape[0]
    P = 2 * (YY * matrix(K.numpy()) * YY)
    p = matrix([0.0]*n)
    G = -spdiag([1.0]*n)
    h = matrix([0.0]*n)
    A = matrix([[1.0 if YY[i,i]==+1 else 0 for i in range(n)],
                [1.0 if YY[j,j]==-1 else 0 for j in range(n)]]).T
    b = matrix([[1.0],[1.0]],(2,1))
    solvers.options['show_progress']=False
    sol = solvers.qp(P,p,G,h,A,b,initvals=init_sol) 
    margin2 = sol['primal objective']
    return sol, margin2





class GRAM(TwoStepMKL):

    direction = 'min'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.func_form = summation


    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return super().get_params()


    def initialize_optimization(self):
        YY          = spdiag([1 if y==self.classes_[1] else -1 for y in self.Y])
        Y           = torch.tensor([1 if y==self.classes_[1] else -1 for y in self.Y])
        weights     = uniform_vector(self.n_kernels)
        ker_matrix  = self.func_form(self.KL, weights)
        alpha,r2    = opt_radius(ker_matrix)
        gamma,m2    = opt_margin(ker_matrix, YY)
        obj         = (r2 / m2) / len(self.Y)

        #caching
        self.cache.YY = YY
        self.cache.Y  = Y
        self.cache.alpha = alpha
        self.cache.gamma = gamma

        dual_coef    = torch.Tensor(np.array(gamma['x'])).double().T[0]
        bias = 0.5 * (dual_coef @ ker_matrix @ (dual_coef.T * Y)).item()

        return Solution(
            weights=weights, 
            objective=obj,
            ker_matrix=ker_matrix,
            dual_coef = dual_coef,
            bias = bias,
            )

        


    def do_step(self):

        YY    = self.cache.YY
        alpha = self.cache.alpha
        gamma = self.cache.gamma

        beta = np.log(self.solution.weights)
        beta = self._update_grad(self.solution.ker_matrix, YY, beta, alpha, gamma)

        w = np.exp(beta)
        w /= w.sum()
        ker_matrix = self.func_form(self.KL, w)
        try :
            # try incremental radius/margin optimization
            new_alpha,r2 = opt_radius(ker_matrix   ,init_sol=alpha)
            new_gamma,m2 = opt_margin(ker_matrix,YY,init_sol=gamma)
        except :
            new_alpha,r2 = opt_radius(ker_matrix   )
            new_gamma,m2 = opt_margin(ker_matrix,YY)
        obj = (r2 / m2) / len(self.Y)

        self.cache.alpha = new_alpha
        self.cache.gamma = new_gamma

        ker_matrix = self.func_form(self.KL, w)

        dual_coef    = torch.Tensor(np.array(new_gamma['x'])).double().T[0]
        yg = dual_coef.T * self.cache.Y
        bias = 0.5 * (dual_coef @ ker_matrix @ yg).item()
        return Solution(
            weights=w,
            objective=obj,
            ker_matrix=ker_matrix,
            dual_coef = dual_coef,
            bias = bias,
            )

        

    def _update_grad(self,Kc, YY, beta, alpha, gamma):
        n = self.n_kernels
        gammaY = gamma['x'].T * YY
        gammaY = torch.DoubleTensor(np.array(gammaY))
        gamma = torch.DoubleTensor(np.array(gamma['x']))
        alpha = torch.DoubleTensor(np.array(alpha['x']))
        
        eb = torch.exp(torch.tensor(beta))
        a,b = [], []
        for K in self.KL:   #optimized for generators
            #K = matrix(K.numpy().astype(np.double))
            #a.append( 1.-(alpha['x'].T*matrix(K)*alpha['x'])[0] )
            #b.append( (gammaY*matrix(K)*gammaY.T)[0] )
            a.append(1. - (alpha.T @ K @ alpha).item())
            b.append( (gammaY @ K @ gammaY.T).item() )
        a, b = torch.tensor(a,  dtype=torch.double), torch.tensor(b,  dtype=torch.double)
        ebb, eba = (eb @ b).item(), (eb @ a).item()
        den = ((eb @ b)**2).item()
        num = [eb[r] * (a[r]*ebb - b[r]*eba) for r in range(n)]
        
        new_beta = np.array([beta[k] - self.learning_rate * (num[k]/den) for k in range(n)])
        return new_beta
```

Apply GRAM algorithm:

```
from MKLpy.callbacks  import EarlyStopping, Monitor
from MKLpy.scheduler  import ReduceOnWorsening
from MKLpy.model_selection import train_test_split
from MKLpy.metrics import pairwise
from MKLpy.generators import Multiview_generator
from MKLpy.algorithms import GRAM

train_ratio = 0.75
validation_ratio = 0.15
test_ratio = 0.10


K = Multiview_generator([X_mrna, X_meth, X_protein], kernel=pairwise.linear_kernel) 

KLtr, KLte, Ytr, Yte  = train_test_split(K, y, test_size=1 - train_ratio)
KLtr, KLva, Ytr, Yva = train_test_split(KLte, Yte, test_size=test_ratio/(test_ratio + validation_ratio)) 

monitor = Monitor()
scheduler = ReduceOnWorsening()

earlystop = EarlyStopping(KLva, Yva,patience=5,cooldown=1,metric='roc_auc',)
mkl_gram = GRAM(
    max_iter=1000,          
    learning_rate=.01,      
    callbacks=[earlystop, monitor],
    scheduler=scheduler).fit(KLtr, Ytr)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArithmeticError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvxopt/misc.py:1429, in kkt_chol2.<locals>.factor(W, H, Df)
   1428 if type(F['S']) is matrix: 
-> 1429     lapack.potrf(F['S']) 
   1430 else:

ArithmeticError: 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ArithmeticError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py:2065, in coneqp(P, q, G, h, dims, A, b, initvals, kktsolver, xnewcopy, xdot, xaxpy, xscal, ynewcopy, ydot, yaxpy, yscal, **kwargs)
   2064 for rti in W['rti']: rti[::rti.size[0]+1 ] = 1.0
-> 2065 try: f = kktsolver(W)
   2066 except ArithmeticError:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py:1981, in coneqp.<locals>.kktsolver(W)
   1980 def kktsolver(W):
-> 1981     return factor(W, P)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvxopt/misc.py:1444, in kkt_chol2.<locals>.factor(W, H, Df)
   1443 if type(F['S']) is matrix: 
-> 1444     lapack.potrf(F['S']) 
   1445 else:

ArithmeticError: 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [31], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 mkl_gram = GRAM(
      2     max_iter=1000,          
      3     learning_rate=.01,      
      4     callbacks=[earlystop, monitor],
      5     scheduler=scheduler).fit(KLtr, Ytr)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MKLpy/algorithms/base.py:91, in MKL.fit(self, KL, Y)
     89     self.solution = self.clf.solution
     90 else :
---> 91     self._fit()                 # fit the model
     93 self.is_fitted = True
     94 return self

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MKLpy/algorithms/base.py:98, in MKL._fit(self)
     97 def _fit(self):
---> 98     self.solution = self._combine_kernels() # call combine_kernels without re-preprocess
     99     if self.learner:
    100         self.learner.fit(self.solution.ker_matrix, self.Y)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MKLpy/algorithms/base.py:217, in TwoStepMKL._combine_kernels(self)
    214 def _combine_kernels(self):
    216     self.learning_rate = self.initial_lr
--> 217     self.solution = self.initialize_optimization()
    218     for callback in self.callbacks: callback.on_train_begin()
    219     self.convergence = False

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MKLpy/algorithms/GRAM.py:77, in GRAM.initialize_optimization(self)
     75 weights     = uniform_vector(self.n_kernels)
     76 ker_matrix  = self.func_form(self.KL, weights)
---> 77 alpha,r2    = opt_radius(ker_matrix)
     78 gamma,m2    = opt_margin(ker_matrix, YY)
     79 obj         = (r2 / m2) / len(self.Y)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MKLpy/algorithms/GRAM.py:35, in opt_radius(K, init_sol)
     33 b = matrix([1.0])
     34 solvers.options['show_progress']=False
---> 35 sol = solvers.qp(P,p,G,h,A,b,initvals=init_sol)
     36 radius2 = (-p.T * sol['x'])[0] - (sol['x'].T * K * sol['x'])[0]
     37 return sol, radius2

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py:4485, in qp(P, q, G, h, A, b, solver, kktsolver, initvals, **kwargs)
   4475         pinfres, dinfres = None, None
   4477     return {'status': status, 'x': x, 's': s, 'y': y, 'z': z,
   4478         'primal objective': pcost, 'dual objective': dcost,
   4479         'gap': gap, 'relative gap': relgap,
   (...)
   4482         'residual as primal infeasibility certificate': pinfres,
   4483         'residual as dual infeasibility certificate': dinfres}
-> 4485 return coneqp(P, q, G, h, None, A,  b, initvals, kktsolver = kktsolver, options = options)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py:2067, in coneqp(P, q, G, h, dims, A, b, initvals, kktsolver, xnewcopy, xdot, xaxpy, xscal, ynewcopy, ydot, yaxpy, yscal, **kwargs)
   2065 try: f = kktsolver(W)
   2066 except ArithmeticError:
-> 2067     raise ValueError("Rank(A) < p or Rank([P; A; G]) < n")
   2070 # Solve
   2071 #
   2072 #     [ P   A'  G' ]   [ x ]   [ -q ]
   2073 #     [ A   0   0  ] * [ y ] = [  b ].
   2074 #     [ G   0  -I  ]   [ z ]   [  h ]
   2076 xcopy(q, x)

ValueError: Rank(A) < p or Rank([P; A; G]) < n
```

Input:

`mrna_df.iloc[0:4,0:4]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01': {'AADAT': 6.22565668754941,
  'ABCB6': 8.88994408176988,
  'ABCB9': 7.63002607924622,
  'ABHD1': 4.44668632713815},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01': {'AADAT': 6.170389794965,
  'ABCB6': 9.09364811306327,
  'ABCB9': 7.76961109298212,
  'ABHD1': 5.9260824660449},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01': {'AADAT': 5.52284042813955,
  'ABCB6': 8.7728136979997,
  'ABCB9': 7.20326283373569,
  'ABHD1': 5.53843883525076},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01': {'AADAT': 6.72337288854289,
  'ABCB6': 10.2092692396731,
  'ABCB9': 7.07511328163257,
  'ABHD1': 7.37872402365434}}
)
```

`methylation_df.iloc[0:4,0:4]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01': {'cg00001349': 2.91982935150322,
  'cg09506600': -0.266195780430997,
  'cg18093372': -2.21886912223455,
  'cg23182840': 2.61132640570935},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01': {'cg00001349': 3.18178018117433,
  'cg09506600': 3.66127491467573,
  'cg18093372': 1.54037692823511,
  'cg23182840': -1.79602557853906},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01': {'cg00001349': 4.18499151289161,
  'cg09506600': -1.53498211627565,
  'cg18093372': -2.36944533302082,
  'cg23182840': -0.853529780223778},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01': {'cg00001349': 2.23780927076746,
  'cg09506600': -0.230680016194668,
  'cg18093372': -0.213643485846856,
  'cg23182840': -1.04586272492208}})
```

`protein_df.iloc[0:4,0:4]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01': {'Smad4': 0.53031080975,
  '14-3-3_epsilon': 0.10028027475,
  'IGFBP2': -0.27061545625,
  'S6_pS235_S236': 0.30110602225},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01': {'Smad4': -0.096913032,
  '14-3-3_epsilon': -0.0086484960000001,
  'IGFBP2': -0.335268579,
  'S6_pS235_S236': -0.3745811985},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01': {'Smad4': 0.330359758,
  '14-3-3_epsilon': 0.355386269,
  'IGFBP2': -0.670854249,
  'S6_pS235_S236': -0.6540221245},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01': {'Smad4': -0.0341280585,
  '14-3-3_epsilon': -0.0887603205,
  'IGFBP2': -0.1709274405,
  'S6_pS235_S236': -0.805935077}})
```

Potential solution:

A google group [discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/cvxopt/c/qlu3CK1TdVQ) suggested that removing redundant constraints may resolve the issue. However, the error persisted even with:

```
GRAM().fit(KLtr, Ytr)
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a more minimal example to try to isolate the issue? See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).